# Need assistance doing some specific formatting to an integer (java)

Tags: java, decimalformat

Alright im working on a radio program, and currently the radio frequencies are integers such as; 107900, 87900.

I need to convert numbers like that into strings that look like this,

107.9, 87.9

I've been playing around with DecimalFormat but haven't had any success. Any tips or hints are appreciated!

Here are some things i've tried,

```
frequency = 107900;
double newFreq = frequency / 1000;
String name = String.valueOf(newFreq);
result = 107.0

double freqer = 107900/1000;
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
result = 107.0

int frequency = 107900;
DecimalFormat dec = new DecimalFormat("#.0");
result = 107900.0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as to not mess about with floating point, and assuming they're all one digit after the decimal (as radio stations are here, anyway), you can use:

```
String.format ("%d.%d", freq / 1000, (freq / 100) % 10)
```

See, for example, the following complete program:

```
public class Test {
    static String radStat (int freq) {
        return String.format ("%d.%d", freq / 1000, (freq / 100) % 10);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("107900 -> " + radStat (107900));
        System.out.println(" 87900 -> " + radStat ( 87900));
        System.out.println("101700 -> " + radStat (101700));
    }                          
}
```

which outputs:

```
107900 -> 107.9
 87900 -> 87.9
101700 -> 101.7
```